# Update TextView from seperate java file

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

I have three files: MainActivity.java, MapsActivity.java and MainActivity.xml. I would like to change this TextView object in the MainActivity.xml:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/destination_latlng"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="Destination Lat, Lng" />
```

I would like to change it from within the MapsActivity.java file, but whenever I try to do this by assigning a variable to the "destination_latlng" TextView and using setText() the app crashes.

```
public class Map extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    // Destination coords
    TextView destination_latLng;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Retrieve the content view that renders the map.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);


        // destination coords
        destination_latLng = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.destination_latlng);
        destination_latLng.setText("testing...");
```

How do I change the TextView from the MapsActivity.java file?

Comment: Show your work. What exactly have you tried doing in your activity file? `var textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.destination_latlng)` and then doing `textView.text = "Whatever you want it to be"` should work fine and can be done in the `onCreate()` method of your activity's class.

Comment: I created a new variable `desntination_coords = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.destination_latlng)` and then tried `destination_coords.setText("testing...")` within the OnCreate but the app crashes on startup of the second MapsActivity.java

Comment: Include a stacktrace in your post, it's impossible to debug your crash without it.

Comment: This is the stacktrace error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: You are trying to call the `.setText()` method on a null object. Seemingly you are fetching the textview component incorrectly as it is null. As I mentioned, show your work in your post. Show all the code you have in your main activity.

Comment: Please see updated post @NoName123

Comment: Is the `TextView` snippet from `MainActivity.xml` ? If so you'll need to post the layout xml for `activity_map`.  That's the only layout in context.

Comment: Yes the `TextView` snippet is from `MainActivity.xml`. What use is the layout xml for the map activity?

Comment: It's the layout used for the Map activity which is where your problem is.  The root context of the screen is the layout specified in `setContentView` so unless there is a `R.id.destination_latlng` in there you'll get the null pointer exception.  Why would you want to update the text view of an activity that is not visible?

Comment: My understanding of R.id is that it searches all avaiable id's in all xml files, is this incorrect? If so, that is my problem. The textview is used in another activity that is the main screen, and it is visible.

Comment: "Finds the first descendant view with the given ID" - descendant of the layout.  there is ever only one visible activity.

Comment: How do you use findViewById to find the view that is not a descedant of the layout then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to think of Activities/Fragments as temporary windows to your app's data - you should not try to store persistent data in them and you have no guarantee how long they will continue to exist once they are not shown. In your case, MainActivity could have been destroyed by the OS and when you go back a completely new layout would be drawn. You *cannot* access views in MainActivity from a different activity, and you shouldn't try to.

If you have some persistent data, e.g. some text about your destination displayed in MainActivity, you should store it in something like a database, a ViewModel, a singleton, or SharedPreferences. Here's how you could do it using SharedPreferences

When you have a new value to set in the map activity, you update the SharedPreferences value.

```java
public class Map extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        // Anywhere in here you can edit the saved value in SharedPreferences
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
        ed.putString("DEST", "Going Somewhere");
        ed.apply();
    }
}
```

Then if you want to show that saved value in the main activity, you can load it from SharedPreferences in `onResume`

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    // Destination coords
    TextView destination_latLng;
    SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        // If R.id.destination_latlng is in R.layout.activity_main you can
        // ONLY access it in MainActivity
        destination_latLng = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.destination_latlng);        
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        String dest = prefs.getString("DEST", "");
        destination_latLng.setText(dest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tyler for this in depth answer!